# Sum of element-wise division

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product

I want to compute the (row) sum of a matrix $A$ obtained by Hadamard division of $B$ by $C$.

I found that if I were to do instead Hadamard multiplication (i.e. the standard Hadamard product, also called elementwise product), there is the nice formula:

$$\sum_i \left[B\odot C\right]_{ij}=\left[B^TC\right]_{jj}$$

I am trying to find if there is a similar representation when using  Hadamard division, but could not find anything?

Comment: You can replace C by 1./C in your equation, where 1./C is the element-wise inverse of C. I am not sure what you are looking for...

Comment: Well but how would you obtain that using standard matrix multiplication, i.e. the counterpart of B'C?

Comment: Division is a non-linear operation, so it is not possible to express it in terms of linear operations like matrix multiplications, transposes and conjugates. Maybe it is possible to do something using matrix inverses, but I would not count on it...

Answer (score 1):

To vectorize a product, there is a formula involving the Kronecker product.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}\big(XYZ\big) &= (Z^T\otimes X)\,y \\
y &= {\rm vec}(Y)\\
}$$
There's an analogous formula for diagonalization involving the Hadamard product.
$$\eqalign{
Y &= {\rm Diag}(y) \\
{\rm diag}\big(XYZ\big) &= (Z^T\odot X)\,y \\
}$$
The latter formula with $\,(X,Y,Z)\to(B^T,I,C)\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(B^TC) &= (C^T\odot B^T){\tt1} \\
 &= (C\odot B)^T{\tt1} \;\doteq\; A^T{\tt1} \\
}$$
which is the nice formula that you have obtained.

Replacing the Hadamard product $(\odot)$ by division $(\oslash),\,$ requires the
replacement of $C$ by its Hadamard inverse within the diag() operation.

Note that diag() creates a vector from the diagonal of its matrix argument, while Diag() creates a diagonal matrix from the input vector.

Comment: thanks, that's very useful! I guess however that the Hadamard inverse cannot be written in a traditional matrix way?